# Learning Reading without Speech?

Tags: perception, learning

I have this question from wandering how a person, who does not have speech capability or is isolated from people who speaks, could learn how to read? Will a language (A) like English or (B) like Chinese makes difference? How important it is for a normal person to connect the sound to the written word?

I guess the question has been asked. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're interested in, you might be able to find answers to this in data about the native-signer deaf community--which learns language without speech.